# Handling both SSL and non-SSL connections when inheriting from httplib.HTTP(s)Connection

Tags: python, http, https

I have a class that inherits from httplib.HTTPSConnection.

```
class MyConnection(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    httplib.HTTPSConnection.__init__(self,*args, **kw)
    ...
```

Is it possible to turn off the SSL layer when the class is instantiatied so I can also use it to communicate with non-secure servers?

I my case it is known before initialisation if SSL should be used so another solution would be to try to switch the inheritance from *httplib.HTTPSConnection* to *httplib.HTTPConnection*, but I am also not sure how to do this in a sensible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment on @Mark's answer, I like the factory approach he's advocating. However, I wouldn't do it exactly his way, because he makes a new class afresh every time. Rather, this is a nice use case for mixin MI and `super`, as follows:

```
class MyConnectionPlugin(object):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super(MyConnectionPlugin, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
    # etc etc -- rest of initiatizations, other methods

class SecureConnection(MyConnectionPlugin,
                       httplib.HTTPSConnection, object):
  pass

class PlainConnection(MyConnectionPlugin,
                      httplib.HTTPConnection, object):
  pass

def ConnectionClass(secure):
  if secure:
    return SecureConnection
  else:
    return PlainConnection

conn = ConnectionClass(whatever_expression())()
```

etc.

Now, alternatives ARE possible, since a Python object can change its own `__class__`, and so forth. However, like shooting flies with a rhino rifle, using excessive force (extremely powerful, deep, and near-magical language features) to solve problems that can be nicely solved with reasonable restraint (the equivalent of a flyswatter), is NOT recommended;-).

**Edit**: the extra injection of `object` in the bases is needed only to compensate for the sad fact that in Python 2.* the HTTPConnection class is old-style and therefore doesn't play well with others -- witness...:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> class Z(object): pass
... 
>>> class Y(Z, httplib.HTTPConnection): pass
... 
>>> Y.mro()
[<class '__main__.Y'>, <class '__main__.Z'>, <type 'object'>, <class httplib.HTTPConnection at 0x264ae0>]
>>> class X(Z, httplib.HTTPConnection, object): pass
... 
>>> X.mro()
[<class '__main__.X'>, <class '__main__.Z'>, <class httplib.HTTPConnection at 0x264ae0>, <type 'object'>]
>>>
```

The method-resolution order (aka MRO) in class Y (without the further injection of an `object` base) has object before the class from httplib (so `super` doesn't do the right thing), but the extra injection jiggles the MRO to compensate. Alas, such care is needed in Python 2.* when dealing with bad old legacy-style classes; fortunately, in Python 3, the legacy style has disappeared and every class "plays well with others" as it should!-)

Comment: Thanks. Again something I did not know 'super'. This saves me from indenting my whole file to enclose it in the factory code. Will use this.

Comment: @pkit, always glad to help! `super` always needs to be used with care, cfr http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/ , but for this unusual case of mixins needing specialized `__init__`s it's truly a great fit.

Comment: When I use this it seems that HTTP(S)Connection.__init__ are not called. Could it be that I am missing something in this class setup?

Comment: @pkit, that `__init__` would called by the `super...__init__` idiom... IF, as I said, HTTPConnection was new-style, but, alas, it's a bad old legacy style class. Let me edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: There, I've edited to show a workaround and, I hope, explain the root of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. With this info and after also reading James Knight's article I have a better understanding of the 'super' powers.

Answer (score 2):

Per your last paragraph, in Python you can use something like a factory pattern:

```
class Foo:
    def doit(self):
        print "I'm a foo"
class Bar:
    def doit(self):
        print "I'm a bar"

def MakeClass(isSecure):
    if isSecure:
        base = Foo
    else:
        base = Bar

    class Quux(base):
        def __init__(self):
            print "I am derived from", base

    return Quux()

MakeClass(True).doit()
MakeClass(False).doit()
```

outputs:

```
I am derived from __main__.Foo
I'm a foo
I am derived from __main__.Bar
I'm a bar
```

Comment: Thanks for this insight. Still I wonder if this is the only way to handle both cases when inheriting from HTTPSConnection?

Comment: @pkit, a factory approach is not the ONLY way -- it's just BY FAR the BEST way -- simple, clean, direct, flawless. I wouldn't do it exactly as Mark did, in detail (this generates many separate but identical classes) but I'm still +1 on general grounds.

Comment: @Alex, thanks for your response. Looking at the httplib code it seems that only the connect method is re-implemented. Would monkey patching the HTTPSConnection instance with the HTTPConnection.connect method make sense? Or is this just plain ugly?

Comment: @pkit, I dislike monkeypatching on general principles!-) Sometimes it's nevertheless the only viable solution, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you want to use MyConnection for multiple subsequent connections to different hosts. If so, you shouldn't be inheriting from HTTP(S)Connection at all - that class isn't really meant to be used for multiple connections. Instead, just make MyConnection *have* a HTTP(S)Connection.

Comment: In my case I actually use it just for one connection to one host. That's why I know before the instatiation if it should be with SLL or wihtout.